# Passing date in custom GA4 event

Tags: google-analytics-4

I want to start passing dates in my custom Google Analytics 4 events so they can be interpreted in reports. However I could not find a reference in the docs on how to format this date. Is this functionality supported by GA4 custom events, and if so, what format should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field will be interpreted as a string, however you can export the data to BigQuery and manage it there in a custom way.